# How to get around 403 error for wget download

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, urllib, http-status-code-403

Can a contemporary scraper recommend how to get around 403 errors with scrapy?

I've tried using Selenium but to no avail. I've also tried passing in the following header to each response: 
`headers= {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0'}`

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import re
import os
import wget

class LivelinguaCrawlerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'livelingua_crawler'
    allowed_domains = ['www.livelingua.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.livelingua.com/project/']

    def parse(self, response):
        language_links = response.css("div.col-md-4 a::attr(href)").getall()
        for link in language_links[2:4]:
            language = re.match('(.*)(?<=courses)(.*)', link).group(2)[1:-1]
            dir_path = "redacted/" + language
            try:
                os.makedirs(dir_path)
            except FileExistsError:
                pass
            self.dir_path = dir_path
            request = response.follow(link, self.parseCourses)
            request.meta['dir'] = dir_path
            yield request

    def parseCourses(self, response):
        courses = response.css("span.thumb-info-caption h6 a::attr(href)").getall()
        dir_path = response.meta['dir']
        for course in courses:
            request = response.follow(course, self.parseEBooks)
            request.meta['dir'] = dir_path
            yield request

    def parseEBooks(self, response):
        eBooks = response.css("div.row:first-child ul li a::attr(href)").getall()
        for eBook in eBooks:
            wget.download(eBook, response.meta['dir'])
            yield {"ebook": eBook}
```

I get the following errors when I try to wget:

```
wget.download(eBook, response.meta['dir'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wget.py", line 526, in download
    (tmpfile, headers) = ulib.urlretrieve(binurl, tmpfile, callback)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 247, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 531, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 641, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 569, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 649, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `wget`? What about Scrapy media pipeline?

Comment: 403 means that the server doesn't allow access to that URL. What makes you think that another client would change that? If you know of some client that can access the same URL without getting 403, try to capture the exact HTTP request with all headers. Then compare each header field with what you're sending when getting the 403 response.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by gangabass, using a files pipeline is the way to go here.
This can be done pretty easily:

Add the files pipeline and set the field containing the url to download in **settings.py**:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.pipelines.files.FilesPipeline': 1}
FILES_URLS_FIELD = 'ebook'
```

The error-code you currently have when trying to download is probably related to the headers as Roland Weber said. To get around this problem I would suggest creating a class that inherits from FilesPipeline and overwrites the get_media_requests method:

```
class DownloadEbooksPipeline(FilesPipeline):
    headers = {
      'Connection': 'keep-alive',
      'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36',
      'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
      'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en;q=0.9,nl-BE;q=0.8,nl;q=0.7,ro-RO;q=0.6,ro;q=0.5,en-US;q=0.4',
    }

    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
        for ebook_url in item.get(self.files_urls_field, []):
            request = Request(url=ebook_url,
                              headers=self.headers)
            yield request
```

If you do it this way, you'll have to change the ITEM_PIPELINES in settings.py to refer to the file containing this class of course.